# How can acoustic velocity of plane wave be derived using acoustic pressure?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I am going though the section on plane travelling waves from the book by G.D.Pierce,"Acoustics: An Introduction to Physical Principles and Applications". I am unfortunately stuck at a place where the author has used operator factoring to get the acoustic velocity.

These are the snapshots of two pages which contain the equations where I am stuck at:
Page 1: https://ibb.co/yQTPQmW
Page 2: https://ibb.co/rvT6p5F

I have understood the process upto Eq 1.7.5.  However, I am confused as to how the author generated Eq 1.7.5b and Eq 1.7.6c.

What's the missing link ? Can someone please provide some pointers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that Pierce is going about this point in a confusing and extremely mathematical manner.  An alternative approach is to simply substitute Eq. (1-7.4) back into the second of Eq. (1-7.1) and solve for $v$.  You will be left with a constant of integration that you can set equal to zero and you will be left with Eq. (1-7.6).

If you want to follow Pierce's logic, though, Eq. (1-7.5a) is just a summary of what happens when you add or subtract Eqs. (1-7.1).  Eqs. (1-7.1) may be written as
\begin{align}
  \rho_0c^2\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} &= - \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}, \\
  \rho_0 c\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} &= - c\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}.
\end{align}
Adding and subtracting these equations yields, respectively,
\begin{gather}
  \rho_0 c\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right) = -\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + c\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\right), \\
  \rho_0 c\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} - c\frac{\partial v}{\partial s}\right) = -\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} - c\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\right).
\end{gather}
Recall from the text just before Eq. (1-7.3) that
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta} \hspace{15mm} c\frac{\partial}{\partial s} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}. $$
Making this change of variable to the sum and difference equations then yields
\begin{gather}
  \rho_0 c\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta} -\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}\right) = -\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial \eta} -\frac{\partial p}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial \eta}\right), \\
  \rho_0 c\left(\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta} + \frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}\right) = -\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial \xi} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial \eta} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial \xi} - \frac{\partial p}{\partial \eta}\right),
\end{gather}
which simplify down to
\begin{gather}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}\left(\rho_0 c v + p\right) = 0, \\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\left(\rho_0 c v - p\right) = 0,
\end{gather}
which are exactly Eqs. (1-7.5b).  These equations imply that $v= -p/\rho_0c$ for $p$ that is independent of $\xi$, and that $v=p/\rho_0c$ for $p$ that is independent of $\eta$.  Since, by definition, $f$ is only a function of $\xi$ and $g$ is only a function of $\eta$, Eq. (1-7.4) then implies that
$$ v = \frac{1}{\rho_0c}\left[ f(\xi) - g(\eta) \right] = \frac{1}{\rho_0c}\left[ f(t-c^{-1}s) - g(t+c^{-1}s) \right], $$
which is Eq. (1-7.6).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I worked out the addition/subtraction and got the Eq 1.7.5b.  These equations are independent of $\varepsilon$ and $\eta$. However, I did not understand how you connected the dependency of functions $f(\varepsilon)$ and $g(\eta)$ to Eq1.7.4 and arrived at Eq 1.7.6.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks once again.